# DeclarationError: Identifier already declared

Tags: solidity, remix

contract Counter {
uint public Count = 0;

```
event Increment(uint value);
event Decrement(uint value);

function getCount() view public returns(uint) {
    return Count;
}

function Increment() public {
   Count += 1;
   emit Increment(Count);
}

function Decrement() public {
   count -= 1;
   emit Decrement(Count);
}
```

}

please what is already defined or wrong

Comment: event names and function names are same. use different name for functions

Answer (score 0):

As said *@Yilmaz*, your issue refers that events and functions name have the same name.
To solve this issue, you must change name to events or function names.
In the following lines, I put an example how you will solve it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Counter { 
    uint public Count = 0;
    // NOTE: I changed name to these two events
    event EventIncrement(uint value);
    event EventDecrement(uint value);

    function getCount() view public returns(uint) {
        return Count;
    }

    function Increment() public {
        Count += 1;
        emit EventIncrement(Count);
    }

    function Decrement() public {
        Count -= 1;
        emit EventDecrement(Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say Thank You